# c# Interop.Word Join two WordDocument without saving to disk

Tags: c#, merge, office-interop, mailmerge

I already can join two or more word documents from their file path.

How can i join them without saving them to disk?

```
string TemporaryPath = "";
string TemplatePath = "";
Object MissingValue;
object OFalse = false;
object OTrue = true;

public WordWorker()
{
    TemporaryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Temporary";
    MissingValue = Missing.Value;
    TemplatePath = @"C:\TemplateTest.dotx";
}
public void Merge()
{
    object wdPageBreak = 7;
    object wdStory = 6;


    Application WordApplication = new Application();
    Document WordDocument = WordApplication.Documents.Add(ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        string Path = CreateWordFromTemplate(WordApplication, TemplatePath, new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "Name", "MyNewValue" + i } });
        WordDocument.Application.Selection.Range.InsertFile(Path, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref OFalse);
    }

    object WordSaveFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument;
    object MergedDocumentPath = TemporaryPath + "Merged.dox";
    WordDocument.SaveAs(ref MergedDocumentPath, ref WordSaveFormat, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue);
    WordApplication.Application.Quit();
}
public string CreateWordFromTemplate(Application WordApplication, Object oTemplatePath, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    Guid DocumentID = Guid.NewGuid();

    Document WordDocument = new Document();

    WordDocument = WordApplication.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue, ref MissingValue);

    foreach (Field FieldToMerge in WordDocument.Fields)
    {
        Range FieldRange = FieldToMerge.Code;
        String FieldText = FieldRange.Text;

        if (FieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
        {
            Int32 EndMerge = FieldText.IndexOf("\\");
            Int32 FieldNameLength = FieldText.Length - EndMerge;
            String FieldName = FieldText.Substring(11, EndMerge - 11).Trim();

            if (dictionary.ContainsKey(FieldName))
            {
                FieldToMerge.Select();
                WordApplication.Selection.TypeText(dictionary[FieldName]);
            }
        }
    }
    string Path = @"{0}\{1}.doc".SFormat(TemporaryPath, DocumentID);

    WordDocument.SaveAs(Path);
    WordDocument.Close();
    return Path;
}
```

Comment: Word doesn't have in-memory or stream interface, as stated here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/84f1ac3f-f078-4087-a627-351d6bb57173/how-to-get-document-content-in-byte-array?forum=vsto  Maybe you could use the clipboard, or look for 3d parties.

Comment: maybe this will help? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/287358/Word-Interop-And-Csharp-How-to-merge-or-more-doc

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these libraries which don't require the Office COM and and a result work directly with the binary data associated therein memory or otherwise.

https://www.codeplex.com/site/search?tagname=office&projectsearchtext=%22office%22

Then hypothetically, using a `MemoryStream` you would be able to create the documents you desire in the formats you desire and then do whatever with that `Stream` you desire.

v/